# MYSQL - want to select some rows, sometimes the field won't be there, but i want to use a WHERE on that field when it is there

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

ok this is hard to explain...

i have the following tables:

```
table : words
table: word_progress
table: word_set

foreign keys:
words.id = word_set.word_id
word_progress.word_id = words.id
word_progress.user_id = users.id
```

basically a word is in a word_set. word_progress (it keeps score on a certain word) relates to a user_id and word_id.

the problem is sometimes there is not an entry in word_progress for user_id and word_id. but when it IS there, i wanna be able to use word_progress in the WHERE part of the query. but if it is not there I dont. My work around at the moment is before running the statement, i do an "insert IGNORE IF EXISTS into work_progress (word_id,user_id) values (?,?)" to make sure its there

i have this query

```
select 
words.* , 
word_progress.progress from words

left join word_progress on word_progress.word_id = words.id
left join word_set on word_set.id = words.word_set_id        

where word_set.id = ?  and word_progress.user_id = ?
```

but... the problem is sometimes there is no word_progress entry for that word

how can i do this?

Comment: Can't you put `word_progress.user_id = ?` as part of the JOIN criteria?

Comment: If there's no data available for a field in a particular row, you'll just get a NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're already left-joining, so when there's no data available, you'll just get `null` as value for your `word_progress`-fields. just check for that like this:

```
...
and
  (
    word_progress.user_id is null
  or
    word_progress.user_id = ?
  )
```

another way would be to add the user-restriction directly to the `join`-criteria like this:

```
...
left join word_progress
  on word_progress.word_id = words.id
  and word_progress.user_id = ?
...
```

and drop that criteria from the `where`-part.

note that, in both cases, you'll have to handle the `null`-cases for `progress` later in your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, this is ambiguous: " i wanna be able to use word_progress in the WHERE part of the query. but if it is not there I dont. "

in the left joins,
if there's no word_progress to match a word, you'll still get a result row for the word, it's just that all the fields of word_progress will be null.

Same for word_set:  no corresponding word_set, then word_set.id and all  the rest are null.

so include 'is null' or 'is not null' in your where clause depending on what you want.... think about that case, that's what you left ambiguous.  or remember that 'a = b' is false if either a or b is null (even if they're both null), so design your where clause to fit.